# is there any web analytic tool that can be hosted on my server?

Tags: php, server-side, web-analytics-tools

i am wondering if there is any web analytic tool like Google analytic but that can be hosted on my own web server.. some code of php for server side with javascript for client side?!
any help?
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at either [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) or [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/).

Comment: thanks femi for the fast response.. i think OWA is the best specially that it have great features like mouse tracking and DOM elements tracking..

Comment: I've generally used Piwik: I haven't gotten into any of the analysis that needs mouse tracking or DOM elements tracking, but OWA might need to be looked at again.

Comment: Piwik is more stable and popular than OWA and has more features, but not the mouse/DOM tracking indeed.